# Font family not recognized when there is a space in the name

Tags: .net, itext7, google-fonts, pdfhtml

I have a .NET 6 application and it runs in a container where I installed the google fonts in the system fonts folder.

With that I put the DefaultFontProvider to also get the system fonts. I have already confirmed that the fonts are indeed being registered and most fonts work fine.
However, when there is a font-family that has space in the name,
pdfHTML does not recognize that font-family.

An example source is: Playfair Display
In the recorded sources there are some for this family:

```
'Playfair-Italic[opsz,wdth,wght].ttf'
'PlayfairDisplay-Italic[wght].ttf'
PlayfairDisplaySC-Black.ttf
PlayfairDisplaySC-BlackItalic.ttf
PlayfairDisplaySC-Bold.ttf
PlayfairDisplaySC-BoldItalic.ttf
PlayfairDisplaySC-Italic.ttf
PlayfairDisplaySC-Regular.ttf
'PlayfairDisplay[wght].ttf'
'Playfair[opsz,wdth,wght].ttf'
```

Another point to note is that when I just put Playfair in the font-family in the css of my HTML element, it can find a corresponding font.

I would like to know if there is something I can do so that these font families with spaces in the name must be linked directly to the font file, or what is the best way to make this reference between the name of a font family and its files? ?

I've already tried to reference the file directly using @font-face, without success.
I also tried registering the source using

```
FontProgramFactory.RegisterFont("usr/share/fonts/truetype/google-fonts/PlayfairDisplaySC-Regular.ttf", "Playfair Display");
var fontProgram = FontProgramFactory.CreateRegisteredFont("Playfair Display");
fontProvider.AddFont(fontProgram);
```

But still the Playfair Display font-family was not recognized.

Note that this behavior applies to all fonts that have a space in the name. It seems to me that when registering the system fonts it does not have a reference to which font-family the file that is being registered is.